# Why am I getting a 422 error in my jQuery call.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I'm using this exact same function for a different xml and it works perfectly. This function was actually working perfectly yesterday now I wake up today and its giving me a 422 error.

```
useEffect(()=>{


  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json',
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        rss_url: 'https://basketball.realgm.com/rss/wiretap/0/0.xml',
    }
}).done(function (response) {
  if(response.status !== 'ok'){ throw response.message; }

  let a = response.items
  let b = a.filter((el, i) => {
  return !el.title.toLowerCase().includes('realgm')
})

  setNewNews(b)



});

},[])
```

Comment: The error -> `{"status":"error","message":"Feed could not be converted, probably not a valid RSS feed."}`  So it looks like `api.rss2json.com` doesn't know how to decode, you might want to contact dev's  for that one.  https://rss2json.com/contact

Comment: Just a note: Using a website to decode rss, really seems overkill.  Any reason you just don't decode directly and avoid `api.rss2json.com` totally.  There is even a NPM module for it -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-to-json

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949542/http-error-422-unprocessable-entity-when-calling-api-from-python-but-curl-wo) 422 means "Unprocessable Entity". So apparently there's something wrong with the XML. Apparently they posted something that created invalid XML. Nothing Stack Overflow can do about it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about an error thrown by an external service.